# Get ID of item in ASP.NET Listview on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a button on each row of a listview.
I have a method on the click event in which I would like to get the ID of the data item.
I placed a `hidden field` in the list view to store the ID.
However,

```
ListView1.FindControl("hiddenField") is returning null.
```

I have tried several different event args, but only the blank event args is working with this button, so I don't have anything in the event args.
I tried to set the command of the button to call commandEventArgs, but no matter what event args I use besides "eventArgs" I get:

> No overload for 'btnManage_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

How do I get the event args into this button?

**EDIT**

Button is in ItemTemplate section of following ListView

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True" DataKeyNames="Id" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" >

 <LayoutTemplate>
              <table id="Table2" class="table" runat="server">
                <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                  <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                    <table runat="server" id="itemPlaceholderContainer" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999; border-style: none; border-width: 1px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" border="1">
                      <tr id="Tr2" runat="server" style="background-color: #DCDCDC; color: #000000;">
                        <th id="Th1" runat="server"></th>
                        <th id="Th2" runat="server">Name</th>
                        <th id="Th3" runat="server">Manage</th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="Tr3" runat="server">
                  <td id="Td2" runat="server" style="text-align: center; background-color: #CCCCCC; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000;"></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use like this

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# DisplayIndex %>'/>
```

Check out the API

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewcommandeventargs.aspx

If you have a button then simply

```
 protected void templateButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Button myButton = (Button)sender;
 }
```

### More details

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcommand.aspx

### Edit 1

Suppose that you have a property "id" then you can use like this

```
  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id")'
```

### Edit 2

As it is case sensitive and you have

```
 DataKeyNames="Id"
```

So you should use as follows

```
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id")'
```

and use it like follows

```
 int i = Convert.ToInt32(myButton.CommandArgument.ToString());
```

Comment: Looks good, but I get this:
//
The name 'DisplayIndex' does not exist in the current context.
//
I am on .NET 3.5

Comment: @hyperGeoMetric you can use your property instead.

Comment: ooooohhhhh. i thought that was going to work but it didn't like this: "int i = Convert.ToInt32(myButton.CommandArgument);". it said: "Input string was not in a correct format." My button has: "CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'

Comment: @hyperGeoMetric can you put html of you list view

Comment: <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True" DataKeyNames="Id" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" > The button is in ItemTemplate

Comment: That worked! The data key name is Id for the field named ID. I think both would work. I am still using ID. I was missing the toString which still doesn't make any sense to me since CommandArg is a String. Thank you so much Shekhar - 10 million gold badges for you!

Comment: @hyperGeoMetric you are welcome and I am pleased to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this: 

ListView lv = (ListView)sender
```

Here **sender** is parameter of buttonclick event. then try of get info.

Comment: button is the sender, I get an error trying to cast sender to listview

Comment: Okay. Do u have the id of Listbox?

Answer (score 0):

I use following line of code to send id of item displayed using list view through LinkButton:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" 
                runat="server" 
                Text="Quick View" 
                Font-Size="Small" 
                OnCommand="QuickView" 
                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Hoarding_Id") %>' >   
</asp:LinkButton>
```

And it working fine...